# Drag and drop sorting in AngularJS - "Sorting.create is not a function" error

Tags: angularjs, rubaxa-sortable

Anybody here who has tried [Sortable.js](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) by rubaxa? I'm currently trying to create a sortable list using this library with no success.

Reason why I chose this library was because it doesn't use jQuery.

This is my HTML:

```
<!-- FORCED RANKING QUESTION TYPE -->
    <ul id="forcedranking" class="wizard-contents-container-ul" ng-model="currentQuestionObject.choices" ng-show="isForcedRankingQuestion">
        <div class="answers-container">

            <li ng-repeat="query in currentQuestionObject.choices | orderBy:['sequence','answer']" class="listModulePopup forcedRankingChoice"> 
                {{query.answer}}
            </li>

            <div class="buttons-container">
                <div class="carousel-wizard-btn-container">
                    <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="wizardPrevious()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == 0">Previous</div>
                    <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || wizardNext()" ng-hide="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="showWelcomeMessage === true ? false : disableWizardFeatures()">Next</div>
                    <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="disableWizardFeatures() || showResults() " ng-show="currentQuestionIndex == wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="disableWizardFeatures()">Finish</div>
                </div>
            </div>         
        </div>
    </ul>
```

And this is my code that calls Sortable. I got it from the above link. I'm calling this inside a custom directive.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myCustomModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: '',
        replace: true,                                                  // replace with custom template
        transclude: true,                                               // insert custom content inside directive
        controller: function($scope, $filter, $state, spService, spHelper, itemContainer, ngDialog,  $http) {

    // Other functions go here   


    /*  Drag and drop for forced ranking  */
    var list = document.getElementById("forcedranking");
    Sortable.create(list);          // call Sortable.js

   // ...
```

I've already called the library in my main HTML page. However, when I ran my application, I got a `TypeError: Sortable.create is not a function` message.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT** As requested by Silvinus, here's the console log of Sortable:
[image]

**UPDATE 1:** After finding [this more detailed explanation about Sortable.js](http://jquerycards.com/forms/drag-drop/sortable/), I revised my code like so:

```
   /*  SORTABLE FOR FORCED RANKING  */
   // var list = document.getElementById("forcedranking");
   Sortable.create(forcedranking, {});
```

It's no longer returning an error, but my items won't move when I drag them. Am I missing something still?

Comment: Can you do a console.log of Sortable object ? --> console.log(Sortable);

And post the log please

Comment: Hi Silvinus, I've edited my post to include a screenshot of the log.

Comment: hum... ok it seem's good. Try to create sortable without create method. Just do : new Sortable(list).

Have you got any arrors in console before your TypeError function which can be linked to the Sortable library initialization ?

Comment: None, but after I changed it, I got a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at new Sortable (Sortable.js:72)` error...

Comment: Are you sure to use latest version of sortable ? In line 72 there is no children access (or maybe you use min file)?

Comment: Nope, it's not minified. My Sortable's version is `0.1.6`. Is there a more recent version?

Comment: latest is 1.4.2. Get js file from this : https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/tree/1.4.2. And try to use as their example. Remove div to have just <ul><li>...</li></ul>

Comment: Thanks! Will try this and update you on the results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check my answer here [List items not dragging using Sortable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072836/list-items-not-dragging-using-sortable-js) you have the same problem, you are not using it right with angular. Second there is a big error in your html `<ul>` can only hold `<li>` you shouldn't put a div wrapping the li's this can give you unexpected results in differents browsers and is not valid html.

When you include the [angular-legacy-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-legacy-sortablejs) you will not need to create your custom directive and you will call it with the attr ng-sortable like this:

```
<ul ng-sortable>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Take a read at the doc of angular-legacy-sortablejs and remember to include the sortable.js lib too

Comment: Thanks for this. The custom directive (which is a modal) is needed because it needs to be called in different parts of the site. The `<div>`s are used to call the CSS classes needed to make the page responsive.

I understand that the HTML structure is unorthodox, but we needed to follow the designs created for it. Anyways, this has already been resolved in the SO link you mentioned. Still, thank you for taking the time to answer. :)